# For loop request Laravel

Tags: laravel

Just a quick question guys really thankful for everyone who can help.

How do I foreach loop inside create eloquent in laravel

Here is my code. I'm trying to get and match the answers for their respective survey questions

```
public function answer_survey(Request $request, $id)
{
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $user = User::where('id', $userId)->first();
    $userNectarPoint = UserNectarPoint::where('user_id', $userId)->first();
    $survey = Survey::find($id);
    $survey_questions = SurveyQuestion::where('survey_id', $survey->id)->get();

    $current_nectarpt_value = $userNectarPoint->nectar_points;

    $questionIds = $request->id;
    $questions = $request->question;
    $answers = $request->answer;

    foreach ($answers as $answer) {
        
    }
    foreach ($survey_questions as $survey_question) {
        $userAnsweredSurvey = new UserAnsweredSurvey;

        $userAnsweredSurvey->user_id = $userId;
        $userAnsweredSurvey->user_fullname = $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->middle_initial . ' ' . $user->family_name;
        $userAnsweredSurvey->survey_id = $survey->id;
        $userAnsweredSurvey->survey_title = $survey->title;
        $userAnsweredSurvey->survey_question_id = $survey_question->id;
        $userAnsweredSurvey->survey_question = $survey_question->question;
        $userAnsweredSurvey->answer = $answer;
        

        $userAnsweredSurvey->save();
    }

    $result_nectarpt = $current_nectarpt_value + $survey->reward_points;
    $userNectarPoint->nectar_points = $result_nectarpt;
    $userNectarPoint->save();
    
    return back()->with('status', 'survey_done');
}
```

Comment: please show your request you are sending from web or postman?

Comment: I am testing it using web. I have edited the question to show the whole code